# Way to ignore case in iteration of glob

Tags: python

Is there a simpler way to do the following to iterate over `xls` files regardless of capitalization?

```
for file in [glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.xls')), glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.XLS'))]:
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

glob and the underlying [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) have no flag for case-independence, but you can use brackets:

```
for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, '*.[xX][lL][sS]')):
```

Comment: why iglob and not just glob?

Answer (score 3):

You could do the matching "manually" without `glob`:

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if not file.lower().endswith('.xls'):
        continue
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A scripting language could help here. For example, in Ruby, to see all filespecs containing 'gem' case insensitively, this would work:

```
ruby -e 'puts Dir["*"].grep /gem/i'
```

This could be abstracted into a script that offered parameterized search strings and directories:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# lsi - ls case insensitive

mask = /#{ARGV[0]}/i
dir = ARGV[1] || '.'
puts Dir[File.join(dir, '*')].grep(mask)
```